# How to check if the controller and action actually exist?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

In my app i record all page views in the database, something like this in AppController:

```
$this->Link->save(array(
    'controller' => $this->request->params['controller'],
    'action' => $this->request->params['action'],
    'var1' => $this->request->params['pass'][0],
    'var2' => $this->request->params['pass'][1]
));
```

which works fine, but some of the URLs people (or bots) type in are 404s. How can i check to see if these links are real or not.

Lots of requests i get are from previous websites on the same domain, requests to /images etc that Cake thinks is a controller.

I don't mind if the check happens before entering into the database or after being retrieved from the database in a view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried this myself, but you can try calling [`Router::parse()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php#L512)

You provide the full URL, and the return value will be cake's route array where you can see the values of controller, action etc.

Comment: @Jleagle: Sorry, a bit of a mixup there.. `Router::parse()` is the right one, I've updated the answer.

Comment: But it does not tell whether a controller and/or action actually exists, which is the question i guess! If you do a request http://yourdomain//some/thing/here it  will print:

 Array
 (
  [controller] => some
  [action] => thing
  [named] => Array
   (
   )

  [pass] => Array
   (
    [0] => here
   )

  [plugin] => 
 )

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2 : catching requests before dispatch**

Sadly, the following piece of code is for cakephp 2.2, if you ever upgrade. [see manual page for Dispatch Filters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html)

```
<?php
App::uses('DispatcherFilter', 'Routing');
class HttpCacheFilter extends DispatcherFilter {

    public function beforeDispatch($event) {
        $request = $event->data['request'];

        if ($request->params['controller'] !== 'pages') {
            die('not found');
        }
    }
}
```

**original answer :**

You should not have to check for anything, since Cakephp does it for you in the first place.

In production mode (i.e debug=0), CakePHP will throw a `NotFoundException()` for any undefined Controller and or Action.

In development mode, CakePHP is kind enough to give you a more explicit message.

So please experiment with `Configure::write('debug',0);` in `core.php`

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes it will tell you when you view the page but I am trying to stop people from ever getting to the page in the first place :)

Comment: @Jleagle : then Dispatch Filters is the most cakephp way to go, I think so, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on the insight from http://www.cleverweb.nl/cakephp/list-all-controllers-in-cakephp-2/ something like the following should do it.

```
function check($controller, $action)  {
  $controller = Inflector::camelize($controller);
  App::import('Controller', $controller.'Controller');
  $aMethods = get_class_methods($controller.'Controller');
  if($aMethods) {
    foreach ($aMethods as $idx => $method) {
      if($action==$method) return true;
    }
  } else  {
    //this is probably NOT a controller!
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then calling it like the following, in AppController, perhaps in beforeFilter:

```
$this->check($this->request->params['controller'], $this->request->params['action']);
```

Comment: This works pretty good, but can be refactored down to
`function check($controller, $action) {
  $controller = Inflector::camelize($controller).'Controller';
  App::import('Controller', $controller);
  return method_exists($controller, $action);
}`

Also, probably doesn't take into account plugins, but that doesn't seem to be a problem for me.